# can I get an upper bound on the tail of a binomial variable?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have $X_1,...$ Bernoulli variables with probability $p$ of success.

I want to get an $n$ such that with probability $\delta$

$P(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \ge k) \ge \delta$

This $n$ would of course depend on $k$, $p$ and $\delta$. Can I get an upper bound for that $n(k,\delta,p)$? (meaning, I want some $n(k,\delta,p)$ for which the above holds, the smaller $n$ is, the better.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Consult a discussion of Chernoff bounds like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound

Answer (score 1):

The following observation, which is straightforward to derive, may be very useful here (also with regard to Naga's answer):
$$
{\rm P}\bigg(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {(1 - X_i ) \ge n - k} \bigg) \le 1 - \delta 
$$
implies 
$$
{\rm P}\bigg(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {X_i  \ge k} \bigg) \ge \delta. 
$$